# Yii caching the changes on local machine

Tags: php, apache, caching, yii, localhost

I am facing strange issue. Sometime my Yii page do not reflect changes no matter even if I do hard refresh. Then I need to restart apache & then find my changes worked. This issues only came at local machine setup. Remote Server is working fine and show changes after ftp upload.

This is first time in Yii, I see this type of behavior, I did not do some special Yii/Apache setup.

Comment: Stupid question: what are the differences between your local and your production environment?

Comment: you meaning html , changes or backend behavior/data changes... ?

Comment: @DiegoCoderPlus, backend logic changes. ( and yes view changes as well ). So If I change some logic at php then it do not reflect in page until I did not restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly why this happens, but try to check your local machine setup and see, if there is any caching mechanism, like Varnish cache or something.